# Running two bash files in one code

Tags: java, c++, bash

I have a Java program that needs to call a certain C++ program twice, via a Bash script: once in the main class, and once in another class. Here is my code to call the Bash script:

```
String args1 = "bash.sh";

try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args1);

    BufferedReader read =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    proc.waitFor();
    try {
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    while (read.ready()) {
        System.out.println(read.readLine());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

and here is the Bash script (`bash.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/Codes/CPM_System/source/GcEqClass X_LE.txt 1 out
```

where `GcEqClass` is the compiled C++ program, `X_LE.txt` is the input-file, `1` is a parameter, and `out` is the output-file.

The problem is that the first time the above code is run (i.e., from the main class), it runs fine, but the second time (i.e., from a different class), `GcEqClass` can't open `X_LE.txt` for reading — `fopen` returns `NULL` here:

```
in = fopen(filename,"rt");
if(in==NULL)
{
    printf("Error: cannot open file %s for read\n", filename);
    exit(-1);
}
```

Oddly, I tried putting both calls in the main Java class, and then they both worked; it's only when one is in the main class, and one is a different class, that the second one doesn't work.

Comment: maybe because you are trying to use the same stream both the times.

Comment: We need to see the full code. It would appear that you're not properly closing/destroying/cleanup the first call and so the 2nd one fails.

Comment: Maybe the first GcEqClass is opening X_LE.txt for input exclusively and so the second GcEqClass can't open it at the same time. We'd need to see more code. What's the relevant code from GcEqClass? What is errno after the failed fopen() call? Etc, etc.

Comment: If this is Java 5 or higher, don't use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`; use a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: @JunedAhsan: Thanks for your comment. I tried with different bash files (same content, but different names) and it doest not work.

Comment: In the `GcEqClass`, close files (`X_LE.txt` and `out`) once you are done reading/working with them. By the time `GcEqClass` finish, both file handles but be released.

Comment: If you need to repeat a task in two different parts of your code, you should place that task in a method that can be called from both so that you can minimize the chances of making an error.

Comment: In a POSIX environment, when `fopen` returns `NULL`, it sets `errno`. So instead of printing a vague error message that just says you couldn't open the file, you should use `perror` to print a specific message that indicates why.

Comment: Also, if you're going to describe something as "C++", you might as well actually write it in C++, for example by using `std::ifstream` to read from a file.